# Monitor mouse coordinates in real-time in Linux

Tags: python, linux, mouse

I need a python coding to monitor mouse coordinates in real-time in Linux. I found below coding and it works well, but the mouse coordinates information will be shown in a pops up GUI window. Now I don't need it show in a GUI window, just need save the mouse coordinates information to a text file(Log file). Does anyone can help me that? Thanks! Plus, it would be great if it can save mouse coordinates information by hourly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Corrected, the thread stops now.
"""

import sys
import os

from time import sleep

import gtk
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

import threading

# uses the package python-xlib
# from http://snipplr.com/view/19188/mouseposition-on-linux-via-xlib/
# or: sudo apt-get install python-xlib
from Xlib import display


old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')


def mousepos():
    """mousepos() --> (x, y) get the mouse coordinates on the screen (linux, Xlib)."""
    data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
    return data["root_x"], data["root_y"]


class MouseThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.label = label
        self.killed = False

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                if self.stopped():
                    break
                text = "{0}".format(mousepos())
                self.label.set_text(text)
                sleep(0.01)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            sys.exit()

    def kill(self):
        self.killed = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self.killed


class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Mouse coordinates 0.1")
        self.set_size_request(250, 50)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.connect("destroy", self.quit)

        label = gtk.Label()

        self.mouseThread = MouseThread(self, label)
        self.mouseThread.start()

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed.put(label, 10, 10)

        self.add(fixed)
        self.show_all()

    def quit(self, widget):
        self.mouseThread.kill()
        gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PyApp()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Here's an [official example](https://sourceforge.net/p/python-xlib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/examples/record_demo.py)  demonstrating the recording of mouse motion, clicks and key presses. The code can easily be adapted to write the data to a file.

Answer (score 10):

Going over the code you provide. The information you want comes from *def mousepos()*. So with just

```
from Xlib import display
data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
data["root_x"], data["root_y"]
```

You get the current mouse position, put this in a loop and write/append to a file.
That should do the trick.

Comment: 1. If you have conda, `conda install -c conda-forge python-xlib` .

Comment: 2. in pip: `pip install python-xlib`